# "Specialmente" versus "particolarmente"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, adverbs

Ho dubbi sull'uso degli avverbi "specialmente" e "particolarmente", che mi sono sempre sembrati molto simili. Non riesco a capire le diverse sfumature di significato tra questi vocaboli. Ad esempio, quali tra queste frasi sono corrette? E se due forme sono corrette, qual è la differenza tra una e l'altra?

- Mi piacciono specialmente i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich.
- Mi piacciono particolarmente i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich.
- Il lugubre timbro del controfagotto mi sembra specialmente misterioso e intrigante.
- Il lugubre timbro del controfagotto mi sembra particolarmente misterioso e intrigante.

Comment: La frase sul controfagotto, nella prima versione, mi sembra un calco dall'inglese (*especially* e *intriguing*). L'aggettivo *intrigante*, fino a poco tempo fa, aveva un significato ben diverso; ora molti lo adoperano, purtroppo, nell'accezione di *intriguing*.

Comment: Interessante, @egreg! Quale aggettivo si potrebbe usare al posto di "intrigante"? "Affascinante", "allettante"?

Comment: Anche *interessante* o *coinvolgente*.

Answer (score 3):

So che si tratta di una domanda relativamente vecchia, ma forse posso dare un contributo, visto che non vi sono risposte accettate.

Probabilmente un linguista potrebbe dare maggiori informazioni tecniche, ma da madrelingua credo che oltre il chiaro rapporto fra i due sinonimi ci sia una leggera differenza di connotazione.

**Specialmente** viene usato per mettere in risalto un elemento che spicca rispetto alla massa.

**Particolarmente** viene usato per rimarcare un... ahem... particolare attributo.

Giocando con i tuoi esempi:

> Mi piace particolarmente Shostakovich, specialmente i suoi quartetti d'archi.

Ovvero quel musicista ti piace molto, ma fra le sue opere ti piacciono soprattutto i quartetti d'archi.

> [...] specialmente il lugubre timbro del controfagotto mi sembra particolarmente misterioso e intrigante.

Ovvero fra le tante caratteristiche di una sinfonia si individua qualcosa di speciale nel lugubre timbro del controfagotto, **molto** misterioso e *intrigante*. Per inciso condivido con egreg il commento su *intrigante*.

Probabilmente la confusione sta nel fatto che i domini semantici di *speciale* e *particolare* sono molto simili se non uguali, ma gli avverbi *specialmente* e *particolarmente* non sono completamente interscambiabili, almeno nella comune parlata italiana del 2016.

Tornando alle tue frasi originali:

> Mi piacciono specialmente i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich.

Questa frase sembra corretta, *specialmente* se vuoi rimarcare che, fra tutte le opere del compositore o perfino fra tutte le opere di musica classica, proprio i suoi quartetti d'archi sono i tuoi preferiti.

> Mi piacciono particolarmente i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich.

L'enfasi qui viene spostata leggermente sul fatto che i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich ti piacciono proprio tanto, a prescindere dal resto del panorama musicale. Ma la frase, inserita in un particolare contesto, potrebbe anche avere lo stesso significato che se avessi usato *specialmente* (es. *Ascolto spesso le sinfonie di Shostakovich, ma mi piacciono particolarmente i suoi quartetti d'archi*).

> Il lugubre timbro del controfagotto mi sembra specialmente misterioso e intrigante.

Leggendo e rileggendo questa frase, mi sembra che qualcosa non torni. Probabilmente la posizione dell'avverbio non corrisponde al suo significato: in quella posizione solo *particolarmente* sembra avere davvero senso, mentre *specialmente* potrebbe essere portato all'inizio della frase e riferirsi all'intero commento, come in uno dei miei esempi precedenti, in cui il timbro del controfagotto viene selezionato dal resto degli elementi in quanto *particolarmente speciale* ;-)

Comment: Cosa intendi per "connotato"? (vedi questa domanda: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/differenze-tra-connotato-e-connotazione).

Comment: Ho usato il termine sbagliato. Ho modificato la risposta usando il termine "attributo".

Answer (score 2):

Nelle frasi che hai scritto effettivamente non ci sono differenze di significato, ma in altre frasi a volte si preferisce l'uso di specialmente o di particolarmente.

Ad esempio

> Oggi Luca è particolarmente nervoso!

è corretta, chiara nel significato ed è comunemente usata
(Luca è normalmente nervoso, ma oggi in maniera particolare).

Invece

> Oggi Luca è specialmente nervoso!

suona davvero strana, e credo che non venga utilizzata.
Ovviamente è corretta, ma non usata.

Answer (score 1):

"Amo la musica classica. Mi piacciono specialmente/particolarmente i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich."

"Mi piacciono particolarmente i quartetti d'archi di Shostakovich."

"Il lugubre timbro del controfagotto mi sembra particolarmente misterioso e intrigante."

"Specialmente" forse suonerebbe strano senza altre premesse. Ma un "particolarmente" come sinonimo di "molto/abbastanza" è usato frequentemente.