# Differenze tra "connotato" e "connotazione"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Fino a poco tempo fa non sapevo dell'esistenza del vocabolo "connotato". L'ho visto per la prima volta nei commenti a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5508/707) là dove io avrei usato "connotazione". Ho cercato il significato di questi due termini nel vocabolario Treccani:

> - ***[connotato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/connotato/)*** s. m. [comp. di *con-* e *notato*, part. pass. di *notare*]. – Ciascuno dei tratti esteriori (colore degli occhi, dei capelli, forma del naso, del viso e altri segni caratteristici) che determinano l’aspetto fisico di una persona e che in documenti personali, passaporti e sim. vengono notati insieme con le generalità per il riconoscimento della persona stessa; si adopera comunem. al plur.: *i suoi c. furono resi noti*; pop. e scherz., *cambiare i c. a qualcuno*, deformargli i lineamenti con percosse o sim.
> - ***[connotazione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/connotazione/)*** s. f. [dal lat. mediev. *connotatio -onis*, der. di *connotare* «segnare insieme, in aggiunta»]. – In linguistica, elemento accessorio che, insieme con la *denotazione*, contribuisce a costituire il significato di una parola in un determinato contesto; consiste nelle sfumature di ordine soggettivo, e cioè i valori allusivi, evocativi, affettivi, che accompagnano l’uso della parola aggiungendosi ai suoi tratti significativi permanenti (per es., *piccino, bambino, pupo, fanciullo, bimbo* hanno uguale denotazione, ma diversa connotazione, in quanto, pur indicando la stessa classe d’oggetti, evocano risonanze affettive e ambientali diverse; nella parola *cuore*, alla denotazione di organo anatomico si accompagnano nella comune coscienza varie connotazioni, di disponibilità affettiva ed emotiva, di coraggio, ecc.).

Se ho capito bene le definizioni del Treccani, questi due vocaboli hanno significati diversi. Non riesco a capire l'uso di "connotato" che se ne fa nei commenti a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5508/707): non penso che là si parli dei tratti esteriori di una persona. Potreste spiegarmi quali sono le differenze di significato e di uso tra "connotato" e "connotazione"?

Comment: È principalmente usato al plurale ***connotati*** con riferimento ai tratti esteriori di una persona: ---* s.m. (spec. pl.) Caratteristica somatica di una persona (SIN) fattezze, tratti: i connotati  di una persona || cambiare i connotati a qlcu., picchiarlo fino a renderlo irriconoscibile; usato anche in senso scherz.*

Comment: L'uso di connotazione è quello corretto, ma vista anche l'assonanza i due termini sono diventati interscambiabili nell'italiano comune.

Comment: @Josh61: Questo è più o meno quello che spiega il Treccani. Capisco che si possa usare "i connotati" per parlare dei tratti fisici di una persona, ma non capisco l'uso di "connotato" simile a quello di "connotazione".

Comment: @Charo - puoi fare un esempio  dove viene usato col significato di connotazione?

Comment: @Josh61: Ce ne sono nei commenti al post che ho citato, ma anche se ne trovano su Internet: http://www.raisport.rai.it/dl/raiSport/Articoli/Perezsaluto-non-ha-connotato-politico-cf3b8a3a-3662-4a5e-bf47-b0a3aaaff877.html

Comment: Connotato ( ling.) Detto di significato aggiunto a quello primario: espressione c. (Hoepli). Si ha anche questo significato. Personalmente non lo uso e preferisco *connotazione*. A me suona molto da *connotati fisici*. Comunque è corretto.

Comment: @Josh61: Questa definizione è del Sabatini Coletti?

Comment: Connotato: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/connotato.shtml

Comment: @Josh61: Vedo nel Sabatini Coletti (nel link che hai messo) però che si tratta di un aggettivo e non di un sostantivo.

Comment: Beh... la domanda è qui per tutti quanti!

Comment: Io sono uno di quelli a cui viene spontaneo usare “connotato” nel senso di “connotazione”. Se mi viene spontaneo usarlo, sarà perché l'ho letto o sentito così, il che però non basta. Per dare una giustificazione più concreta, ipotizzerei che sia un uso sostantivato del participio passato di “connotare” (che ha, quello sì, l'uso di cui pariamo: «In filosofia e in linguistica, designare un oggetto considerandolo sotto un particolare aspetto» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/connotare/))), così come si parla di un “portato”, di un “significato”, di un “vissuto” etc.

Comment: Bene, @DaG. A me è sembrato strano questo uso di "connotato", ma immagino che sia perché nella mia lingua esiste una parola simile a "connotazione" però no una simile a "connotato". Cercando "connotato" nel dizionario mi sono sentita ancora più confusa e per questa ragione ho posto la domanda.

Comment: Hai fatto benone, @Charo: la mia è solo una congettura.

Answer (score 2):

***Connotato è un aggettivo e un nome***. Come nome viene esclusivamente usato in riferimento ai tratti fisici di una persona, come aggettivo si riferisce al significato di **connotare**;  ossia di *definire, caratterizzare qualcosa per mezzo di una sua proprietà*:

[Connotato](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=connotato): (Garzanti)

♦ agg.

> - (m
>     f. -a; pl.m. -i, f. -e)
>     *nei significati del verbo* ([connotare](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=connotare)).

♦ n.m.

> - (m pl. -i /
>     spec. pl.) *ciascuno dei tratti somatici e dei segni caratteristici che identificano una persona*.

In termini linguistici si usa il termine ***connotazione*** per riferirsi ad un   *elemento accessorio che, insieme con la denotazione, contribuisce a costituire il significato di una parola in un determinato contesto*.

Penso che usare il termine *connotato* con il significato di *connotazione* sia un estensione del termine stesso (*tratti, aspetti fisici vs tratti e aspetti linguistici*) e sotto questo aspetto sia un espressione accettabile. Credo che  questo sia il senso usato nella frase:

*la parola “popolino” lo ha eccome, ***un connotato negativo***.